# Checking Internet Connection in release mode does not work

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to check for internet connection before making an api request. Following is my helper function to check internet

```
Future<bool> checkInternetConnection() async {
  try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      return true;
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The helper function above works properly when in debug mode for Android, but for release mode in Android it returns false even when internet connection is available. I tried with both Wifi and Mobile data. The above functions works properly in iOS.

Comment: java code is working?

Comment: I think you should file an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md) and did you try this in another phone?

Comment: @HasanKucuk what java code, this is dart.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I tried on Coolpad which has Marshmallow as well as on OnePlus 6 which has Pie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add Internet permission in `your-flutter-app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` in `android` directory of Flutter app. Your app works in debug mode because Internet permission must be there in `your-flutter-app/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- Add this in src/main/AndroidManifest.xml inside android directory of Flutter app -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```